# Regex an innerHtml of a table to find special charcters

Tags: regex

I'm having an hard time to get this..

I have this html code:

```
<table border='1'><tr><th></th><th>Fact Questions Report Type Count</th></tr><tr>
<td class=' sorting_1'>0 - 18</td><td>78</td></tr><tr><td class=' sorting_1'>19-64</td>
<td>78</td></tr><tr><td class=' sorting_1'>65+</td><td>78</td></tr><tr>
<td class=' sorting_1'>אין גיל</td><td>78</td></tr><tr><td class=' sorting_1'>נפטר</td>
<td>78</td></tr><tr><td class=' sorting_1'>Unknown</td><td>78</td></tr></table>
```

As you see there are special characters that I want to catch like those:

`אין גיל` , `נפטר`

I thought to do a regex that will exclude all words `\W` and numbers `\D` and those->`=|'`

But i can't get it work..

The perfect solution will be getting two items with the special charcters... `אין גיל` , `נפטר`

P.S: There could be other special charcters

I will love to see an example for this in here : [RegexPal - Online Editor](http://regexpal.com/)

tnx!

Comment: This may critically depend on what regex engine you're using. PHP? C#? Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to catch characters in the Hebrew language specifically, you can try

```
[\u0590-\u05FF\s]+
```

assuming spaces are okay, or, if using a more advanced regex engine,

```
[\p{Hebrew}\s]+
```

If you're actually trying to catch non-English but printable characters then it's hard to help you without seeing what you've tried. `\D` is a subset of `\W`, so you should only need `\W+`, or if I understand you correctly in that you want to exclude `->=|'` as well, then `[^\w>=|-]+` (the dash must come last here (or in the second position after `^`)).

Answer (score 1):

This one matches only [ASCII printable characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters):

```
[\x20-\x7e]
```

To catch those `אין גיל` , `נפטר` (among many other non ASCII characters) you need

```
[^\x20-\x7e]
```

As requested: [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%5E%5Cx20-%5Cx7e%5D&input=%3Ctable%20border%3D%271%27%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Cth%3E%3C%2Fth%3E%3Cth%3EFact%20Questions%20Report%20Type%20Count%3C%2Fth%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3Ctr%3E%0A%3Ctd%20class%3D%27%20sorting_1%27%3E0%20-%2018%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E78%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%27%20sorting_1%27%3E19-64%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%3E78%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%27%20sorting_1%27%3E65%2B%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E78%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3Ctr%3E%0A%3Ctd%20class%3D%27%20sorting_1%27%3E%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9F%20%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E78%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%27%20sorting_1%27%3E%D7%A0%D7%A4%D7%98%D7%A8%3C%2Ftd%3E%0A%3Ctd%3E78%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3Ctr%3E%3Ctd%20class%3D%27%20sorting_1%27%3EUnknown%3C%2Ftd%3E%3Ctd%3E78%3C%2Ftd%3E%3C%2Ftr%3E%3C%2Ftable%3E)

Answer (score 1):

> I thought to do a regex that will exclude all words \W and numbers \D and those =|'

Simply do it: `[^\w\d=|']+`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

- Visualization on [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/x29oB4DmTHxJjEZ2)
- Demo on [RegExr](http://regexr.com?376mn)

Note that you can't use `[^\W]`: since `\W` means anything but `\w`, `[^\W]` means anything but anything but `\w`, i.e. `\w` (`- x - = +`).